# Where is the css file being defined?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, css

I'm editing an aspx layouts and its master page, and somebody has already linked a custom css file in designer in the Manage Styles pane.

Where is this defined in the code? I can't find it anywhere. I'd like to link to a QA.css while only checking in draft versions, so the transition to publishing a major version is instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attach a style via Manage Styles whilst editing the MasterPage, the code is inserted into the Master Page in the HEAD section at the top of the page.

If you're editing an ASPX page, then the link rel tag is inserted inside an asp:Content tag with placeholder id "PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead".